# Create a radio button list like the image

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

So I am taking a class and we have to create a ordering page. I can do almost everything thats required, except, the radio list box. The problem I am having is that it needs to look as similar as possible to the image below! I have created the radio list box, but I cannot figure out how to create the greyish border, and title. I am guessing the title of the box may be a label with a width and background color but the instructions seem to want just the radio list box. Anyway, if anyone has an idea how to recreate this example image it would be much appreciated.

[Radio list box with a outline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8L8DE.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a panel, with a label that have text weight set to bold, and the background of the panel set to darkgrey.

Comment: Thank you, I was missing the panel!!! The instructions dont say to use one but, apparently, I am supposed to. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome - please remember to flag as answer;-) Have a nice weekend.

Comment: Sorry I had to wait until it would let me select it as answer!